# running an executable in parallel by dividing the input directory tree

Tags: shell, utilities, parallelism

Commands like `find` and `grep` would benefit greatly if they were to run in parallel. Is there a utility or a program that takes a command as an argument and makes it run in parallel by running multiple threads of the command, each on a subset of the directory tree?

Comment: See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85859/variable-declaration-in-parallel-sh-c. There's a tool called parallel which will do what you want. Also you can use xargs to divide up file trees like so: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63772/speeding-a-find-rm-command-with-test-through-parallelization.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `xargs` has a `-P` command for that.

```
find . ... -print0 | xargs -r0P4 -n10 some-command
```

Will run up to 4 `some-command`s at a time with up to 10 files as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Actually commands like `find` and `grep` are almost always IO-bound: the disk is the bottleneck, not the CPU. In such cases, if you run several instances in parallel, they will compete for I/O bandwidth and cache, and so they will be slower.

With a command that is more CPU-intensive, or in rare cases (e.g. a very fast RAID-1 that isn't otherwise busy together with a slow CPU), you can use tools such as [GNU parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) or the [`-P` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Controlling-Parallelism) of recent versions of GNU xargs.

Assuming that file names do not contain newlines, the following commands invoke `cpu_intensive_command` on each file in turn, with two parallel threads:

```
find -type f | xargs -I {} -P 2 cpu_intensive_command {}
find -type f | parallel -X --number-of-cpus=2 cpu_intensive_command {}
```

An alternative strategy is to divide the work in two parts that you estimate are approximately equal. This requires no fancy tools, but does not balance the jobs between the processors.

```
cpu_intensive_command [a-m]* &
cpu_intensive_command [!a-m]*
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Walk through GNU Parallel's tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html and watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1